# Connect Android device to web service in VirtualBox

Tags: android, web-services

i have in my laptop in virtualbox a UbuntuServer with a webservice at ip: 192.168.1.46, and webservice, ServerName is api.webservice, so from my laptop if i try in the browser api.webservice it works well!.
Now the problem, from the android device not work, the webservice,laptop and device are connect in the same network, from the device if i try in the browser 192.168.1.46, it tell me it works, but if i try api.webservice not work..

there are any solution?

Comment: Please post your virtual machine network settings

Comment: there is: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.frapi
    ServerAdmin admin@api.frapi
    DocumentRoot FRAPI_PATH/src/frapi/public 

    # This should be omitted in the production environment
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
                  
    <Directory FRAPI_PATH/src/frapi/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is a problem with name resolution.
Your laptap (Windows?) is able to resolve "api.webservice", but your Android device not.

It highly depends on your infrastructure (WLAN-Router, DHCP-Server) how to solve this problem. You could perhaps provision your WLAN-Router/DHCP-Server to permanently bind api.webservice to the IP address of your Ubuntu box, so Android device can make a NS-lookup.

I suppose your Android app will connect a real Internet server in future. In this case, I wouldn't bother connecting the webservice by IP-address for test purposes.

When your app is published and used outside your local network, name resolution will work when connecting to a internet server registered in "official" DNS.

Comment: i have a dinamic Server DHCP in my router, in my laptop(also linux) i set in /etc/hosts  192.168.1.46 api.frapi. But in my router where i set this information?

Comment: It depends on your router. Which model do you have?

Comment: In the [docs](http://www.asus.com/Networking/DSLN10/#support) I haven't found a description how to setup static ip addresses. Try to dig into something like "LAN" -> "DHCP". Some routers provide an IP-range for dynamic addresses and offer a way to add static routes. You can test it by removing entry in /etc/hosts and try to connect your Ubuntu e.g. via ping, wget, curl, ...

Comment: If your laptop received its IP-address from your router (and DHCP-server), then you could try if your Android device is able to resolve hostnames from dynamically provided IP-adresses. Connect your Android device in debug-mode, start `adb shell` and in the shell `ping mylaptopname`. If you can see s.t. like `PING mylapttopnam (192.168.1.22) ...` then you have luck. It means that your DHCP server resolves dynamically registered hosts. If your Ubuntu box uses DHCP als well and you have configured the hostname correctly, it could work.

Comment: i have in my router--> server DHCP i can if i want add a manual ip, but it ask me a MAC address and a IP address

Comment: if i try ping mylaptopname, i have:  PING antonio-HP-Pavilion-Sleekbook-15 (212.52.82.27) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- antonio-HP-Pavilion-Sleekbook-15 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4003ms

Comment: if i test and remove entry in /etc/hosts not work.. i try to add a virtual server in my router but still nothing, i can set DHCP in manually but ask me a MAC address

Comment: You can find out the MAC address by `sudo ifconfig -a` in your Ubuntu box. There should be a line like `eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:4f:ea:ca:fe`. The 6 values in hex is your MAC-Address. Try to configure a static entry, but better don't conflict w/ DHCP address range. BTW the IP-Address of your notebook does confuse me a bit. I'd expected an internal address like 192.168.1.xxx. Strange...

Comment: not works.. now if i try 192.168.1.46 in my device, i see in browser "it works" but if i try api.frapi still nothing

Comment: Can you initiate chat w/ me? I haven't got enough rep :-(

Comment: now or tomorrow 9-12 CET. If you've got problems reaching me via chat, search for my alias, you'll find my email address, e.g. on github.